# Java8: Using an IntStream as a Supplier parameter for custom Collector

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream, collectors

For stream objects, is it not possible to use the collect method to write a custom Collector object that will collect to another stream object? I have just recently learned about streams and am trying to get as much experience with them as possible and I ran into this problem.

My code is:

```
    // method to return how many unique letters are used in
    // the Strings in the given stream
    public int uniqueLetters(Stream<String> stream){
        // transfer Strings to an uppercase char stream
        IntStream allLets = stream.collect(IntStream::empty, 
                          (s1, s2) -> { String toAdd = s2.toUpperCase();
                                        IntStream cs = toAdd.chars();
                                        IntStream.concat(s1, cs); //exception thrown on this line
                                       }, IntStream::concat); 
        // use distinct on char stream and count
        return (int) allLets.distinct().count();
    }
```

This code compiles and the collect method runs fine for the first String in the stream, but the second time it reaches IntStream.concat(s1, cs) I get the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed

The way I interpret this is that once my first String is converted to an IntStream and the collect method moves to the next String, my first IntStream gets closed. Is that correct? Why does this happen?

This was an exercise I invented for myself to try to get more experience with streams and functional programming. I know this probably isn't the best way to write this method. I'm interested in knowing why this doesn't work, not in what other approach I could take.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By calling `concat`, you are not mutating `s1`. `concat` *returns* the concatenated stream. Streams are not mutable in the first place.

This means that the `Stream.empty` you started with never changed, and it is used in the `concat` method again and again. However, you *can't* use a stream in `concat` twice. That counts as "operate upon the stream". So when you try to do it the second time, you got an illegal state exception as documented:

> A stream should be operated on (invoking an intermediate or terminal
>   stream operation) only once. This rules out, for example, "forked"
>   streams, where the same source feeds two or more pipelines, or
>   multiple traversals of the same stream. A stream implementation may
>   throw IllegalStateException if it detects that the stream is being
>   reused. However, since some stream operations may return their
>   receiver rather than a new stream object, it may not be possible to
>   detect reuse in all cases.

To solve your problem of finding unique characters, you don't need to collect to streams. Just do this:

```
public static int uniqueLetters(Stream<String> stream){
    return (int)stream.flatMapToInt(String::chars).distinct().count();
}
```

`flatMap` is probably what you were trying to do by collecting to streams. Now you know that's called `flatMap`.